# pointer-to-member type and template

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

First I got to class for this test:

```
struct Foo {
  void test() {
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct Bar {
  Foo foo;
};
```

and a template class which accepts a pointer-to-member when constructing:

```
template<typename Type, typename MemberType>
class test {
 public:
  test(Type &t, MemberType Type::* p) : t(t) {
    (t.*p).test();
  }
  Type &t;
};
```

it works well, instantiation can be done by using `test<Bar, Foo> test(bar, &Bar::foo);`, except that it is boring to write `Bar` and `Foo` every time since it can be deduced for `&Bar::foo`, so I decide to make a specialization version:

```
template<typename Type, typename MemberType, MemberType Type::*p>
class test<MemberType Type::*p> {
 public:
  test(Type &t) {
    (t.*p).test();
  }
};
```

ok, I don't really know how to do this, I just want to pass a `MemberType Type::*p` as the only template parameter like this: `test<&Bar::foo> test(bar);`

Then I create a brand new class:

```
template<typename Type, typename MemberType, MemberType Type::*p>
class test2 {
 public:
  test2(Type &t) {
    (t.*p).test();
  }
};
```

now I can pass as a template argument rather than a constructor argument, but this time I have to write three paramters:`test2<Bar, Foo, &Bar::foo> test2(bar);`

So what's the right way on earth that I can simply use `test<&Bar::foo> test(bar);`?

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it correctly.

The primary template has to use an `auto` template parameter (a C++17 feature):

```
template <auto MemberPtr> class test {};
```

Then the specialization:

```
template <typename Type, typename MemberType, MemberType Type::*p>
class test<p> // Note `p` instead of `MemberType Type::*p`.
{
  public:
    test(Type &t)
    {
        (t.*p).test();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

#### An alternative: `test t(bar, &Bar::foo);`

This use your primary template:

```
template<typename Type, typename MemberType>
class test {
 public:
  test(Type &t, MemberType Type::* p) : t(t) {
    (t.*p).test();
  }
  Type &t;
};
```

and [template argument deduction (TAD)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

Live demo: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52ee3ddba011473b

Answer (score 0):

From C++17 onwards this is the exact intended use case for user defined deduction guides. Pre-C++17 one often used make functions for this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename Type, typename MemberType>
class test {
 public:
  test(Type &t, MemberType Type::* p) : t(t) {
    (t.*p).test();
  }
  Type &t;
};

// C++17 user defined deduction guide
template<typename Type, typename MemberType>
test(Type &t, MemberType Type::* p) -> test<std::decay_t<decltype(t)>, decltype(static_cast<std::decay<decltype(t)>>(t).*p) >;

// pre C++17 make function
template<typename Type, typename MemberType>
test<Type, MemberType> make_test(Type &t, MemberType Type::* p) {
    return test<Type, MemberType>(t, p);
}


struct Foo {
  void test() {
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct Bar {
  Foo foo;
};


int main() {
    Bar b;
    test<Bar, Foo> t1 (b, &Bar::foo);
    // Only works in C++17
    test t2(b, &Bar::foo);
    auto t3 = make_test(b, &Bar::foo);
}
```